# eureka task supervisor rejected the task - client does not register with server

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a Eureka client with these two tasks being rejected. This happens every two minutes. The client does not register with the Eureka server. It started happening with a lot of client applications two days ago. Restarting the client application fixes the problem, the client registers with the server.

Eureka Client version: spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:3.1.3
Eureka Server version: spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:2.2.6.RELEASE

I know this is failing because the pool size is 2 and there are two active threads. What can I do to prevent this from happening in the future. I do not want to restart the Eureka Client applications every time this happens.

```
2022-07-27 17:31:02,625  WARN - [scoveryClient-1] c.n.d.TimedSupervisorTask                          : task supervisor rejected the task
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@5094ea41[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@4497e885[Wrapped task = com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread@5df88e08]] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6c6fd47c[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2046]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.netflix.discovery.TimedSupervisorTask.run(TimedSupervisorTask.java:66) [eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
2022-07-27 17:31:13,173  WARN - [scoveryClient-0] c.n.d.TimedSupervisorTask                          : task supervisor rejected the task
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@391a5b77[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@3aea2122[Wrapped task = com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread@a4330bc]] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@60d5c7c8[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1763]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.netflix.discovery.TimedSupervisorTask.run(TimedSupervisorTask.java:66) [eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/907 This Github issue seems related. We're trying to upgrade the Spring Boot and Spring Cloud versions and seeing if that resolves the issue at the moment.